# Canonical URL for Front Page - without path

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases, meta-tags

I've been looking for a solution to the Front Page URL issue that meets the following criteria.

- Allows me to keep the Canonical and Description Tags from Meta Tags Quick on Views sub-pages.
- Allows web client users to change the meta description on the front page through the Meta Tags module.

I use both the Meta Tags and Meta Tags Quick modules for views tagging and automation on standard nodes. Unfortunately I haven't been able to set the /welcome page canonical URL to a forced "http://www.website.com/". I continue to get "http://www.website.com/welcome" for the front page.

I've tried removing the path alias. I've tried setting path specific meta tags with the 'quick' module. I've input the details into the standard Meta Tags module under global front page.

Maybe there is some combination that I'm missing. Any ideas?

Additional: I've been using the Redirect Module on the site - if that matters.

Solution: Alright - after extensive poking around the issue was that I added Canonical URLs as a [current-page:url:absolute] to the GLOBAL settings rather than the Content.

This meant that the GLOBAL Front Page override was overridden by the other elements.

Worked for me, for now. Apparently I can't post the solution that I found with my team because I'm a new user. I don't plan to come back this week and will forget to publish a fix if I don't put it here. Get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - after extensive poking around the issue was that I added Canonical URLs as a [current-page:url:absolute] to the GLOBAL settings rather than the Content.

This meant that the GLOBAL Front Page override was overridden by the other elements.